# Split String in two Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have one string that if have more than 35 characters have to been split in another string. Something like that `var string1 = "1...38"` into `var result1= "1...35`" and `var result2 = "36...38"`. I thinking in using a split but i don't know if is the best option.

Comment: how could you split the string? do you have a delimiter somewhere? It depends on how many pieces you want to end up with and whether you really require `result2` in the end... `take` and maybe `chunked` probably already suffice... if you have a delimiter and only want 2 pieces, you could also use `split(yourDelimiter, limit = 2)`...

Answer (score 9):

[`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html#chunked) is definitely ok if chunking into more then 2 pieces is ok for you too. But if you rather meant splitting it up into at most 2 pieces with the first being of a certain length and the second part only containing the remainder, you may want to use something like the following instead (similar to [s1m0nw1s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54349816/6202869), but) using [`take`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/take.html) and [`substring`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring.html#substring):

```
fun String.splitAtIndex(index : Int) = take(index) to substring(index)
```

Or if you want to play it safe, you can also add some convenience checks:

```
fun String.splitAtIndex(index: Int) = when {
  index < 0 -> 0
  index > length -> length
  else -> index
}.let {
  take(it) to substring(it)
}
```

or if you like exceptions more:

```
fun String.splitAtIndex(index: Int) = require(index in 0..length).let {
  take(index) to substring(index)
}
```

All of those functions return you a `Pair<String, String>`, which you can handle as follows:

```
"someString".splitAtIndex(5).also { (atMost5Chars, remainder) ->
   println("$atMost5Chars | remainder: $remainder")
}
"someOther".splitAtIndex(4).also { 
   (first) -> println(first) // discard the remainder... but then again you could have used also just take(4)
}
```

As you wrote that you thought of using [`split`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html#split) and if you have an appropriate delimiter at hand you may also want to use the following instead:

```
yourInputString.split(yourDelimiter, limit = 2)
```

This will split `yourInputString` into two pieces where the first piece is all the string up to the first occurrence of `yourDelimiter`. Example:

```
val yourInputString = "this is a string with a delimiter | and some more information that is not necessary | with some more delimiters | | |"
yourInputString.split('|', limit = 2).also {
  (uptoFirstDelimiter, remainder) -> println("$uptoFirstDelimiter --- remainder: $remainder")
}
```

which will print:

```
this is a string with a delimiter  --- remainder:  and some more information that is not necessary | with some more delimiters | | |
```

Answer (score 7):

You should rather use

`drop` and `droplast` (returns a String)

```
val chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl"
val result1 = chars.dropLast(3) // returns abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghi
val result2 = chars.drop(35) // returns jkl
```

or `chunked` (returns a list of strings)

```
chars.chunked(35)) // returns [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghi, jkl]
```

that depends on your context

Comment: Why don't you share sudo code? that would make this answer much more useful ;-)

Answer (score 5):

`chunked(size: Int)` will give you back your string split into a list:

```
"Hello There! This is a really long string that I want split".chunked(10)
```

Result

> ["Hello Ther", "e! This is",  "a really" , "long strin", "g that I w", "ant split"]

Comment: Is this what the OP asked for? I think they want to split into max 2 strings

Answer (score 1):

This extension will give you a pair of the limited string associated to the rest:

```
fun String.limit(max: Int): Pair<String, String> =
    if (length > max) {
        take(max) to takeLast(length - max)
    } else this to ""
```

Some examples:

```
val string1 = "onqweinalsdmuizqbwnöfasdkdasqwrwfeqewwqeweqewf" //more than 35
val string2 = "onqweinalsdmuizqbwnöfasdkdasqwrwfeq" //exactly 35
val string3= "asdqwe" //less than 35

println(string1.limit(35))    // -> (onqweinalsdmuizqbwnöfasdkdasqwrwfeq, ewwqeweqewf)
println(string2.limit(35))    // -> (onqweinalsdmuizqbwnöfasdkdasqwrwfeq, )
println(string3.limit(35))    // -> (asdqwe, )
```

Answer (score 1):

Chunked method is what you need. Check this doc ->

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html

Comment: hey! pls add an example and a bit of explanation. link only answers are not very helpful because the content where the link points to can change or disappear. :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar scenario in card payment where expiry month/year is needed to split for api and pass separate params to network repository and this is how it done.
The Solution:
var expiryMonth:String="12/2034"
expiryMonth.split("/").also {
(uptoFirstDelimiter, remainder) -> println("$uptoFirstDelimiter --- remainder: $remainder")
}